# SSIS Decoding XML in Base64Binary from a WebServices Task

Tags: xml, web-services, ssis

Using SSIS/Sql Server 2016, I have set up a WebServices task to download some data from a RESTApi service. I have been able to set up the WSDL and can seemingly call the service OK, because I can see the data being returned into a variable. It looks like it is encoded in base64binary - example here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<base64Binary>Q3VycmVuY3l.... </base64Binary>

where Q3VycmVuY3l.... is a long list of base64 characters.
```

I have managed to insert the data via a stored procedure into a landing table which has just one column [BASE64] of type varchar(max). Now I am trying to process the  data and convert the base64 data into columns and rows. Having read a number of posts I have tried the following (using nvarchar(max) due to UTF-16):

```
--declare vars.

DECLARE @data nvarchar(max), @XmlData xml

--set the base64 encoded varchar.

SET @data = (SELECT [BASE64] FROM Landing.TickXML64)

--construct an xml var.

SET @XmlData = CAST(@data as xml)

--— base64 decode the @data.
SELECT CONVERT(nvarchar(max), 
@XmlData.value('(data)[1]', 'varbinary(max)'))
```

When I evaluate the above I get the following:

```
select @data -- returns: 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>  <base64Binary>Q3VycmVuY3l......

select @xmldata -- returns:

<base64Binary>Q3VycmVuY3l.....
```

However

```
SELECT CONVERT(nvarchar(max), 
@XmlData.value('(data)[1]', 'varbinary(max)'))
```

returns null

Where is this going wrong? Is it because it still has the  tags around it?

If anyone has any smart suggestions for taking in base64 xml data from a webservice in SSIS and inserting it into SQL tables, the assistance would be much appreciated.